# Continue command without loop structure

Tags: java, exception

```
try{
  if(condition A || condition B || condition C)
    do something
}catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
  //Equivalent command to continue
}
```

Suppose I have an exception in condition B and I want it to ignore it and check if condition C is fulfilled. How can I do that if it is not a loop structure and therefore it cannot be used the continue command?

Comment: Throw your custom exception on condition B, inside your catch check for condition C

Comment: The problem is that it is in B as it can be in A. And if the list of conditions was much greater, it would not be quite productive to include one catch for each of them.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

Assuming you do the same operation on all of your conditions of them. (T is your data type)

```
    List<T> conditions = ArrayList<>();
    boolean flag = false;
    for(T condition : conditions) {
        try{
            if(!condition)
                flag = false;
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            //Equivalent command to continue
        }
        if(flag) {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

usually we use condition when we want to check something, not change it.

if one of the condition didn't pass, then there is no reason to continue, or else it wouldn't be a condition.

now there are several suggestion i can give you, but probably the best one will be to initiate the values of the conditions before the try block, and the if after:

```
boolean A = false;
boolean B = false;
boolean C = false;
try{
  A = condition A;// this will probably be a function
  B = condition B;
  C = condition C;

}catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
  //Equivalent command to continue
}

if(condition A || condition B || condition C)
  do something
```

now, we can expend it to 3 try blocks, or even a function like so:

```
private boolean conditionA()
{
   boolean A = false;

   try{
      A = condition A;

    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
      //Equivalent command to continue
    }

    return A;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Guava [Predicate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html):

```
Predicate<MyInput> a = new Predicate(){
    @Override
    public boolean apply(MyInput i) {
        return condition A;
    }
};
Predicate<MyInput> b = new Predicate(){
    @Override
    public boolean apply(MyInput i) {
        try {
            return condition B;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
Predicate<MyInput> c = ...

if(Predicates.or(a, b, c).apply(myInput)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` keyword would not help: you cannot continue evaluating an expression after encountering an exception. If you would like to treat an exception in a condition in the same way as a condition that evaluates to `false`, wrap the condition in a method, and call that method instead:

```
boolean methodForConditionB() {
    try {
        return ... // Actual condition goes here
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
...
if (conditionA || methodForConditionB() || conditionC) {
    ...
}
```

This can be used as a work-around. Generally, however, you should avoid using exceptions for transferring control during regular computations, i.e. outside of exceptional situations. Specifically, `IndexOutOfBoundsException` signals a programming error, so it is hard to imagine circumstances when catching it would be good design.